# Mobile menu bouncing out of overlay when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu

when i go onto a mobile and access the menu of this store i am an employee it bounces out from the overlay when i scroll all the way down. You can replicate by going on a phone, clicking the hamburger icon on the top left, then scrolling the menu down (and then some more), it jumps out from the menu and starts scrolling on the main site. How can i fix this, hope there is some simple css. Thank you very much.

I have experimented with the css and some js but not proficient with that so hoping for css solution

The site  is https://luksushjem.no